# how to pass a variable while calling a Js function in karate

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying to pass a variable that I get from my response as a parameter to a JS function

Something like this 
* def temp = getDate('#variable')

when I call a JS function using a hard coded value it works fine. But this doesn't seem to work,when I want to pass a dynamic value. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused with the `#blah` notation in the docs and examples.

Karate uses JavaScript by default. So you just refer to any variable in scope directly and it will work. For example:

```
* def a = 1
* def b = 2
* def add = function(a, b){ return a + b }
* def c = add(a, b)
* match c == 3
```

So probably, all you need to do is:

```
* def temp = getDate(response.someKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.date-class').valueAsDate  = new Date();
function getDateFn() {
  var a  = document.querySelector('.date-class').value;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="date-class">
<button onclick="getDateFn();">Get date</button>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Karate.